# Magento 2.3 - Display additional attribute on backend order overview

Tags: magento2, attributes, orders

Given scenario:

We have a ton of articles where it would be better for our workflow to add an additional attribute displayed at the highlighted area on the picture, but since i cant find a configuration option for that im going to ask it here.

Is there an easy way to add additional attributes there?

[image]

Comment: Additional attribute mean product attribute?

Comment: Exactly, an additional product attribute

Comment: Suppose, if you a product and its order place a month ago and that time that attribute was X. now that attribute value suddenly changes Product  Y then  what will be show at  at Admin order view page?

Comment: Let me explain it a bit deeper: We are selling mainly suspension parts for various cars. Those products have one SKU as usuall but are fitting in many different cars. Lets say due to the fact that there are X amount of suitable cars we have to choose a generic name that fit to everything - "KW Coilovers Variant 1" for example. Its impossible to see the suitable cars on the SKU nor the prouct name now. The attribute i would want to add is called "additional_fitment_info" and contains a string of the cars platform - for example: "modular transverse matrix (MQB)"

Comment: With that additional information we can see what type of car was ordered and can use that info for additional marketing on sales through multiple channels to see where we can concentrate on and which cars wont go into that much effect on sales. The attribute is also displayed on the PDF's through an additional extension we are using to customize the pdf layout so even our customers and dealers can see that info to check there packing slip upon shipping arrival to assign it to there own workflow in the workshop.

Comment: It can be shell command?

Comment: If i can display them on every order directly under the "SKU" attribute it should be no problem. Not quite sure what you mean by "shell command" since it has to be displayed on every product for every order

Comment: you want to additional attribute value display in highlighted area  Right ??

Comment: Exactly, unfortunately nothing worked yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no configuration option to do this. You need to customize the "product" column by overriding template file `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\items\column\name.phtml`.

[Here](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/overriding-native-template-file-magento-2.html) is the guide to override a template file in case if you need some help to do so.

Please update your new template code to code below to add the additional_fitment_info attribute in your Product column.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
?>
<?php
/* @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name */
?>
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()) : ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU'))?>:</span> <?= /* @noEscape */ implode('<br />', $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data::class)->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Additional Fitment Info: '))?>:</span> <?= /* @noEscape */ $_item->getProduct()->getAdditionalFitmentInfo() ?>
    </div>


    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()) : ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option) : ?>
                <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']) : ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?php $dots = 'dots' . uniqid(); ?>
                        <?php $id = 'id' . uniqid(); ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['value'], ['a', 'br']) ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']) : ?><span id="<?= /* @noEscape */ $dots; ?>"> ...</span><span id="<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['remainder'], ['a']) ?></span>
                            <script>
                                require(['prototype'], function() {
                                    $('<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>').show();});
                                    $('<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @noEscape */ $dots; ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @noEscape */ $dots; ?>').show();});
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After updating the code your order detail page will look like this,

[image: desired output]

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately that didnt work. It doesnt even display the label, even when simply pasting the new code directly in the magento vendor directory. Our attribute is called ```additional_pdf_text``` used as attribute_code. So i thought i should update that also on the changes you made:

```<span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Additional Fitment Info: '))?>:</span> <?= /* @noEscape */ $_item->getProduct()->getadditional_pdf_text() ?>```

Comment: Code posted here is tested by myself (see screenshot) so it should work. You might need to flush your cache if enabled. Also test it by putting static value like `<span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Additional Fitment Info: '))?>:</span> <?= "Test Value" ?>`. If it works than replace `getadditional_pdf_text()` with `getAdditionalPdfText()`

Comment: Still no luck, even with the test value. It wont show the label either. I have run the following command via cli: `upgrade` `di:compile` `static-content:deploy` - Cleared the magento cache and cache storage via backend and even tried to create new test orders to see if it only updates on new orders aswell. I've setup the attribute per storeview, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Found the problem. There was an extension that blocked the changes. Now everything is working  :) Thank you very much